# React Native: process.env has only NODE_ENV

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, environment-variables

I'm setting an environment variable while building my react-native app (on windows):

```
SET APP_ENV=dev & react-native run-android
```

`echo %APP_ENV%` returns 'dev'

But when I log process.env object in my JS file, I only get:

```
{
  NODE_ENV: "development"
}
```

Is there a different way to access environment variables set through command prompt?

Answer (score 19):

It's important to know that the React-Native app is running on a device (or emulator) in an **environment more like a browser**, not a Node.js process.

For cross-compatibility with Node.js libraries that relies on `process.env.NODE_ENV` to perform optimizations, React-Native adds the `process` global variable with `env.NODE_ENV`.

If you want to pass custom constants to React-Native, you can use: https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config

Comment: The github page you linked specifically said: "Keep in mind this module doesn't obfuscate or encrypt secrets for packaging, so do not store sensitive keys in .env. It's basically impossible to prevent users from reverse engineering mobile app secrets, so design your app (and APIs) with that in mind." So if the desired outcome is to have a secure place to write sensitive info, this library doesn't help, right?

Comment: @Oucam i think the point in this phrase is that it will not give you same amount of security you git from it on mobile. Since for mobile apps everything bundled together into apk/ipa someone are able to decompose it back and one way or another find this data.

Answer (score 8):

You should install this plugin babel plugin

```
npm install babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables --save-dev
```

Then add it to your babel config (.babelrc, babel.config.js) in the plugin section

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-inline-environment-variables", {
      "include": [
        "NODE_ENV"
      ]
    }]
  ]
}
```

Then when you pass the variable through the inline like

```
API_KEY=dev && react-native run-android
```

You should get it through

```
process.env.API_KEY
```

And the value will be `dev`

This work for me on Mac terminal, Hope it answer your question

EDIT:
I added a double "&" because only one doesn't work.

Comment: does not work RN 0.68.1

Comment: Make sure you add the names of the required env vars to the `include` array. The babel plugin inlines the env var. It's not "available" on `process.env.API_KEY`, rather `process.env.API_KEY` is replaced with the string literal value of your env var in the output JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I found to solve this problem is by using the `react-native-config` library that you can have a look at [here](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config).

1. Install the library:

```
$ yarn add react-native-config
```

2. Create your `.env` file with your content. For example:

```
GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY=abcdefgh
```

3. Import `Config` from `react-native-config` and use your variables.

```
import Config from "react-native-config";
...
console.log('ENV:', Config.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY); // ENV: abcdefgh
```

*P.S.: After installing the package you need to run `npx pod-install` to auto-link it or if your React Native version is older than 0.60, link it manually following the [instructions on the library](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config#setup).*

Answer (score 3):

Nothing worked out from these answers here, as well as [React Native Expo Environment Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58270059/react-native-expo-environment-variables), but I've found [react-native-dotenv](https://github.com/goatandsheep/react-native-dotenv).

It did the trick:

1. Terminal: `yarn add react-native-dotenv --dev`
2. In `babel.config.js` (or `.babelrc`): add `"module:react-native-dotenv"` to `plugins`
3. In your component, `import { REST_API_KEY } from "@env";` at the top
4. In your component, use as `alert(REST_API_KEY);`

Of course, with the `alert`, that's a dummy example :)

Comment: I made it that way, but I'm wondering if I can just put it inside `process.env` object, if it's not read-only.

Comment: Not sure, I'd expect it's key=value format, not object.

Comment: Thank you, since `from '@env'` works on web with NextJS too, so it's good, I don't need `process.env` anymore, and everything works great with the same app as hybrid with NextJS and Native.

Comment: Interesting. No problems with fetching env variables when building with `eas`/for native apps?

Answer (score 2):

add `babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables`

`npm install babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables --save-dev`

babel.config.js:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-inline-environment-variables"],
  ]
}
```

do not add  `"include": ["NODE_ENV"]`

then run `API_KEY=testKey && react-native start`
and then you can use `API_KEY` via `process.env.API_KEY`,

but it is weird that `console.log(process.env)` only show a `{NODE_ENV: "development"}`,do not contain `API_KEY`

Comment: it should be && instead of & there at API_KEY=testKey & react-native start

Comment: This was absolutely DOA for me :(